Facebook login button only works with users registered as an administrator or developer in the application
When requesting the review for permits, they answered me this:

"The Facebook login button in your app is not working correctly. By clicking on it, the user should be able to log in with Facebook and enter their Facebook account without problems. Make sure this button is working correctly and that it can be accessed from outside your company environment before you resubmit the application for review."

The fact is that with users registered as a developer or administrator it works correctly, but if it is an external person it does not work, I assume that this is why I am rejected.
I leave a couple more details:
When I use a login setting with a "System User Access Identifier" it always fails and says:
"It seems that this application is not available
To resolve this issue, please contact MI_APP"
If I use a login setting with a "User Access Identifier" it works, but only with Facebook accounts that are registered as Administrator or Developer within the app.
I've been stuck with the same problem for quite some time now, I can't make progress on a development that was requested of me and I honestly have no idea what the problem could be.
